# Flutter Images problem while using network.image

Tags: flutter

need some help between the word and images, I want them to space a little bit and dun want them to touch each other.

Example like this :

[image: Example That I want]

The output of my own code with images :
[image: My Own Progress]

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      primary: false,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                              crossAxisCount: 2),
                      itemCount: 10,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        Widget widget;
                        switch (index) {
                          case 0:
                            widget = Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                color: Colors.grey[100],
                              ),
                              child: GridTile(
                                child: Image.network(
                                  'https://static.nike.com/a/images/t_prod_ss/w_640,c_limit,f_auto/qebbe6yb2crumsanfyu4/sacai-x-nike-ldwaffle-black-release-date.jpg',
                                ),
                                footer: Container(
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                  height: 40,
                                  child: const GridTileBar(
                                    title: Text('Sacai x Nike Ldwaffle Black',
                                        maxLines: 2),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                            break;
```

Comment: You can try`TestStyle(height:X)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Stack` widget, just put `Column`, set parent base on the column.